# Not able to read entered number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to use JavaScript and this seems to be really a beginner question. I am trying to make a web page where user can input a number and be able to square it. I have been able to write following code which shows the page with prompt and input fields, button to start calculation and an answer area:

```
<html>   
<head>
      <script>
        function calculate(){
            alert("In calculate fn")    // NOT REACHING HERE; 
            var x = document.getElementByName("SNUM");
            document.getElementById("answer_area").innerHTML = x * x;
        }
      </script>      
</head> 
<body>
      <form>
         <table cellspacing = "2" cellpadding = "2" border = "1">
            <tr>
               <td align = "right">Enter a number: </td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "SNUM" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>      
    <br>
      <button onclick="calculate()">Square it</button>

     <b><u><br><br>Answer:</b></u>
     <p id="answer_area"></p>  <!-- answer to be placed here; -->

</body>
</html>
```

However, there is no response when the button is clicked. Where is the problem and how can this be solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: You have a pretty sum of points to not follow the "How to ask a question" guidelines. Please, add a demo where we can reproduce the problem, because right now is working.

Comment: Note It's [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName#Syntax) notice plural form of Element,  and it returns a collection (array like structure). Even if the line worked you would be multiplying the element object to itself and not the `value` in that element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things in this line

`document.getElementsByName("SNUM")[0].value;`

You need to get the element using index since `getElementsByName` gives a collection. Secondly you need to get the value so use `value` with it and thirdly there is a typo in your code

```js
function calculate() {
  alert("In calculate fn") // NOT REACHING HERE; 
  var x = document.getElementsByName("SNUM")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("answer_area").innerHTML = x * x;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter a number: </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="SNUM" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Square it</button>

<b><u><br><br>Answer:</u></b>
<p id="answer_area"></p>
<!-- answer to be placed here; -->
```

Comment: Great. What is the typo in my code? Also how do you manage this running of code here (any link where this is explained)?

Comment: it should be `document.getElementsByName` instead of `document.getElementByName` , note the `s` in `Elements`. Secondly used stack snippet to run your code

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Use miss `s` in getElement**s**ByName.
>
> 2) `getElementsByName` method return a NodeList Collection of elements so get first with [0].
>
> 3) For get value use of 'value' property.

So Change:

```
var x = document.getElementByName("SNUM");
```

To:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("SNUM")[0].value;
```

```js
function calculate(){
  alert("In calculate fn")    // NOT REACHING HERE; 
  var x = document.getElementsByName("SNUM")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("answer_area").innerHTML = x * x;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table cellspacing = "2" cellpadding = "2" border = "1">
    <tr>
      <td align = "right">Enter a number: </td>
      <td><input type = "text" name = "SNUM" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>      
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Square it</button>
<b><u><br><br>Answer:</b></u>
<p id="answer_area"></p>  <!-- answer to be placed here; -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, the problem is here:

```
 var x = document.getElementByName("SNUM");
```

There is no method called `getElementByName` but rather:

`getElementsByName("SNUM")`

Change your code to:

```html
<html>   
<head>
      <script>
        function calculate(){
            alert("In calculate fn")    // NOT REACHING HERE; 
            var x = document.getElementsByName("SNUM")[0].value;
            document.getElementById("answer_area").innerHTML = x * x;
        }
      </script>      
</head> 
<body>
      <form>
         <table cellspacing = "2" cellpadding = "2" border = "1">
            <tr>
               <td align = "right">Enter a number: </td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "SNUM" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>      
    <br>
      <button onclick="calculate()">Square it</button>

     <b><u><br><br>Answer:</b></u>
     <p id="answer_area"></p>  <!-- answer to be placed here; -->

</body>
</html>
```